# Error "mysql.sock: no such file or directory" while deploying to aws elastik beanstalk

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops, goland

I'm trying to deploy Golang application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but keep getting an error:

```
ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
ERROR   [Instance: i-0ca401a7a27c0fe40] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
```

At logs error occurs here:

```
[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [StageApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: chown /var/app/staging/mysql/mysql.sock: no such file or directory
```

For context, a simple Golang application deploys correctly.

I checked an instance manually with `eb ssh` and `/var/app/staging/mysql/mysql.sock` file actually existing. I was trying to delete `mysql` folder but I still got the same error. Also, I configured the app to use SQLite (this app is not written by me, I`m just trying to deploy it) instead of MySQL, but still no results

Answer (score 0):

AWS Elastic Beanstalk is designed for hosting apps in production, with high availability. In this context, there are normally several application servers (the instances). These can be add or removed at any time, automaticaly. So the database is hosted in its own server, not on the instances of  AWS Elastic Beanstalk. That's why you cannot use a local SQLite or MySQL database. You can use [AWS RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/rds/) for that.

Comment: Was this answer helpfull ? If yes, please consider accepting it or upvoting. Thank you